# Creating clock format from int

Tags: java, parsing, casting, splice

I have been searching, but everything seems so convoluted. I am too accustomed to splicing in python, but I am a java noob.

I get an input which is 4 digits long, and I have to restrict certain digits so that it can be displayed as a clock later. I am using military time. I was trying to convert to a string to get a sub string of what I wanted and then convert it back to an int, but I am getting an in-convertible types error.

```
    String digits = Integer.toString(clockVal);

    if (Integer.parseInt(digits.charAt(0) > 1 ) { // cuz 1st dig can only be 1 or 0
```

Any help is appreciated. PS I cannot change input from an int, either.

Comment: What are the actual error messages you are getting?  What are the actual inputs you are using?  Describing your problem is much less useful than showing what you're actually doing.

Comment: You should strongly consider providing a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.  The code you've posted in your question doesn't compile, which makes it hard to know if your root problem is a logic error or a syntax error.  A working piece of code clears that sort of thing right up.

Comment: Inputs would be like 1000, 1500, or 2400, not 1561 because 15:61 is not a time, just as 2500 would not work, and the error mssage is not clear; I cant copy it, its a pop up.

Comment: I have no idea what the heck you're doing there, but you can't compare a `char` to an int like that and expect to have the correct results. Your parentheses are unbalanced and an integer is not a valid type inside an if-clause.

Answer (score 3):

Say you have a 4 digit int which has to be 24 hour time between 0000 and 2359

```
public static boolean isValid(int time) {
     int mins = time % 100;
     return mins < 60 && hrs >= 0 && hrs < 2400;
}
```

Say it is between 0001 and 2400

```
public static boolean isValid(int time) {
     int mins = time % 100;
     return mins < 60 && time >= 1 && time <= 2400;
}
```

Comment: I like this; it is very very concise compared to my brutish approach. I was having trouble understanding if I would get what I wanted with modulus.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If this is your exact code, you will have a compile time error from the if statement: `(Integer.parseInt(digits.charAt(0) > 1 )`. You are missing a closing parenthesis, so the compiler thinks that you are trying to parse `digits.charAt(0) > 1` (a `boolean` value) into an `Integer`, rather than what you intend (`Integer.parseInt(digits.charAt(0))`).

Answer (score 1):

I like the response of Peter. Attaching my code which was based on Peter's response.

```
package general;

public class ClockPlay {
    ClockPlay() {}

    public static boolean isValidTime (int time){
        int mins = time % 100;
        System.out.println("Mins is:" + mins);
        return (mins >= 0 && mins < 60 && time >= 0 && time <= 2400);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int time1 = 1245;
        int time2 = 2510;

        System.out.println("Validity of Time 1 is:" + isValidTime(time1));
        System.out.println("Validity of Time 2 is:" + isValidTime(time2));
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Mins is:45
Validity of Time 1 is:true
Mins is:10
Validity of Time 2 is:false
```

Comment: I understand even more now about how to effectively use the modulus. Thank you